How to properly detelecidine a video?
I'm using HandBrake to recode a DVD which appears to have a 3:2 pulldown: the framerate is 29.97 fps and two frames out of five have combing artifacts. The result with "Detelecine=Default" looks OK, except for some scene changes, where the ghost horizontal lines from the previous frame remain.
However, according to Avisynth docs there is a solution:

Why am I getting combed frames after some scene changes?


These scene changes require a third (backward) match. Decomb will test the third match only if "post" is set to any value other than 0.

How can I enable a backward match in HandBrake, or any other easy-to-use video converter. I get it that I can make it work with Avisynth, but I'd prefer a ready-made solution to what appears to be a well-known problem, without involving scripting.

It appears that HandBrake is unable to make backward matches, at least currently. The documentation for version 1.8.0 defines the following command line options:
   -9, --detelecine[=string]
                           Detelecine (ivtc) video with pullup filter
                           Note: this filter drops duplicate frames to
                           restore the pre-telecine framerate, unless you
                           specify a constant framerate
                           (--rate 29.97 --cfr)
                           Custom Format:
                               skip-left=s:skip-right=s:skip-top=s:
                               skip-bottom=s:strict-breaks=s:plane=p:parity=p:
                               disable=d
                           Default:
                               skip-left=1:skip-right=1:skip-top=4:
                               skip-bottom=4:plane=0
   --no-detelecine         Disable preset detelecine filter

Avidemux has an almost appropriate plugin, but, as the description says,

Donald Graft Telecide. Replace ivtc pattern by progressive frames. Video stays at 30 fps.

Which means the plugin leaves you with the task to remove duplicate frames from the video. This would be every 5th frame, but the starting index can potentially be different after each scene change.
So, Avisynth seems to be the only viable option currently.
